# how can post the data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am new in ruby on rails. I am trying to add task for the user who is logged in but when i hit the task/new path it show the error in new.html.erb file in form url if i remove the url from form it work but after submit the form the data not save in db

```
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"task", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Task controller

```
class TaskController < ApplicationController
    def get; end

    def index
      @task = Task.all
    end

    def show
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
      @task = Task.new
    end

   def create
      @task = Task.new(params.permit(:tasks).permit(:daily_task, :date, :current_user.id))
    respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
       format.html { redirect_to   @task, notice: 'Task added' }
    else
       format.html { render :new }
    end
    
 end 
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "daily_task"
t.datetime "date"
t.bigint "users_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["users_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_users_id"
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h3>add task</h3>

<%= form_for :task, url: task_path  do |f| %>
  Add task: <%=f.text_field :daily_task %><br>
  date: <%=f.datetime_select :date %>

  <%= f.submit "Add" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You should use `form_with` instead of `form_for`. Although it'll not solve your issue, `form_for` is about to be depreciated. Check out `form_with` documentation: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `rails routes` will show you the available routes in your application:

```
$ rails routes | grep task 

      tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)            tasks#index
            POST   /tasks(.:format)            tasks#create
   new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)        tasks#new
  edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)   tasks#edit
       task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)        tasks#show
            PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)        tasks#update
            PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)        tasks#update
            DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)        tasks#destroy
```

You can suffix the string in the first column by `_path` in order to create usable routes. Example, `tasks_path` will redirect to `tasks#index` and `new_task_path` to `tasks#new`.

Note that some routes are expecting an `:id`, which is the primary key of the record you want to fetch. For `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy`, you want to perform theses actions on **a specific record**.

Therefore, if you're using `task_path`, it involves that you want to fetch a specific record; which isn't correct. Instead, you need to point to `tasks#create` (POST request). You can do it several ways:

```rb
# Considering `@task` is your object. You might be using `task` if you're using partials

<%= form_with model: @task do |f| %>

<%= form_with model: @task, url: tasks_path do |f| %>

<%= form_with model: @task, url: tasks_path, method: :post do |f| %>

<%= form with model: Task.new do |f| %>
```

See [`form_with`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with)

---

**EDIT:** I just noticed the `ruby-on-rails-4` tag, `form_with` will not be available for you.

It's quite the same tho:

```rb
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>

<%= form_for @task, url: tasks_path do |f| %>

<%= form_for @task, url: tasks_path, method: :post do |f| %>

<%= form_for Task.new %>
```

See [`form_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

---

**EDIT2**: about `undefined method 'id' for :current_user:Symbol`

You're calling the method `.id` on a `Symbol`. Plus, you may want to implement [Strong Parameters](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) in a private method.

Untested code, but I'd do something like:

```rb
#/app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb

class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # set user_id in the backend, since POST requests can easily be modified
    parameters = task_params.merge({ user_id: current_user.id })

    @task = Task.new(parameters)
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html # ...
      else
        format.html # ...
      end
    end

  private
  
    def task_params
       params.require(:task).permit(:daily_task, :date, :user_id)   # `user_id` without s
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you still there is one error when i add task it show the error   undefined method `id' for :current_user:Symbol in task controller create method

Comment: Indeed, that's another error. You're calling the method `id` on a `Symbol`, and it tells you that this method does not exists. If you're using an authentication gem (as Devise), you're likely to use `current_user` (without `:`)

Comment: See my update ! You wont be able to copypasta it, but the idea is there (mainly: use `current_user.id` instead of `:current_user.id`).
Upvote if it helps :)

Comment: Enjoy Ruby & Ror. Check https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/, community has written awesome guides !